# What should our chat room be called?

Tags: discussion, chat

Every Stack Exchange site has an official chat room which can be reached by clicking the "Stack Exchange" logo on the upper left corner.

Each site chooses a nickname for its chat room to put some personality into the site.

Please propose a name for the chat room, with one name per answer.

Answer (score 6):

> **Aftermath Coffee Chat**

Pun intended.

Comment: I like the idea with the aftermath, so much I would just call it "Aftermath"

Comment: The post needed more words. Even with "aftermath coffee chat" I had to write something else.

Answer (score 3):

> The Teacher's Lounge
>   ${}{}{}$

Comment: I would strongly recommend to add the term "mathematics" somewhere in that name.

Comment: The **"Teachers' Lounge"** happens to be the name of the chat room shared by Moderators across the network. I would avoid this name to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> [**The Royal Roads**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Road#A_metaphorical_.E2.80.9CRoyal_Road.E2.80.9D_in_famous_quotations) Math Teachers' Lounge