# Renaming the "Mathematics Educators" chatroom.

Tags: discussion, chat

Similar to [**this post,**](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-should-we-name-our-chatroom) would anyone be interested in suggesting a new name?

Comment: Only a handful of users currently participate in the chat rooms.  I don't think there would be much interest in renaming them.

Comment: Perhaps by raising awareness we can increase participation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should our chat room be called?](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-chat-room-be-called)

Comment: Perhaps a moderator can merge this post with [this one](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-chat-room-be-called)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me suggest sticking with the current name. (Which is the default name: Mathematics Educators.)

The discussion about the name of the room can be revived later, if more people start using it. (I would not like to see some people confused whether this is the main chat room for the site, simply because the unusual name of the room.)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest [**The Royal Road**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Road#A_metaphorical_.E2.80.9CRoyal_Road.E2.80.9D_in_famous_quotations)

Answer (score 0):

I like: The Math Teachers' Lounge

Answer (score -1):

I was going to suggest Pythagoras' Salon, because as I say in my math center, "I love that guy".